# How to set the style of the message in an SWT Text field?

Tags: css, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to change the style of the message in an SWT Text field.

```
Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);
text.setMessage("Enter your name");
```

The default styling is to simply make the message grey instead of black. I would like to make it cursive and a lighter shade of grey.

I am using CSS to style the controls but I don't know how to style the suggestion message.

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP using e4 CSS?

Comment: @greg-449 - it is not a pure e4 RCP. It uses the compatibility bridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWT uses the native widgets of the platform it runs on. Their appearance is controlled by the platform and cannot be changed by application code.

The CSS styling is also limited to the properties that the SWT API exposes.

Comment: What is "they"? AFAIK CSS support is "on top of" SWT and hence restricted to what the API exposes.

Comment: I was misreading the question. On my Mac some styling does work for the `setMessage` text but you can't set it separately from the normal text style.